# How to use block instead of inline-block when rendering view

Tags: ember.js

I have implemented a view with multiple {{view Ember.TextField ...}}

The template is displayed BUT all the html  elements are displayed inline...

I would like to have all input elements rendered as block.

How to fix that ? (I would like to avoid adding  after each view in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the classNames binding inherited from Ember.View to set a css class on the element and define your css styles on it (i.e. display: block;), such as:

```
{{view Ember.TextField classNames="some-class" ...}}
```

Alternatively, you can create a subclass of Ember.TextField:

```
App.MyTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    classNames: ['some-class']
});
```

And then call this instead in the Handlebars UI:

```
{{view App.MyTextField ...}}
```